# Best way to open shoes apps when developing

Tags: ruby, shoes

Learning Shoes here. I am wondering if there is a better way to open shoes apps while keeping the console open. Currently I have to first open the shoes app, then open the console, then open my app after each minute change I make just to see what errors I get.

I feel like there is an easier way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: I heard that the author of shoes (why the lucky stiff) disappeared from public, and so shoes is not maintained anymore. You might want to keep that in mind. Someone please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: it is maintained. Check the site: http://shoesrb.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run Shoes from command line, and give it your application as a parameter.

`$ <Path_where_you_have_installed_Shoes>/dist/shoes <your_application>`

The Shoes binary is in `/dist` relative to the installation directory (so you won' find it on PATH automagically)

Comment: Is there an argument to autolaunch the console when I do this? Thanks Karatedog this is very helpful.

Comment: Sorry  I spent probably a minute looking at this page on two separate occasions trying to find the "Accept" before I realized it was the obscure grayed out checkmark. I have to say thats not very obvious.

Comment: I don't have a firm test on autolaunching the console, but I wanted to try out to feed the Shift-/ to the keyboard buffer when running Shoes. I just need to find the appropriate control character :-)

Comment: On the mac Shoes is opened as an application and the console stays open. I can then open apps with command+o. So much easier to work with when developing.

Comment: I've noticed oddness where if you don't reopen the shoes.app every time any classes that are required by your application are cached.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on *NIX, you can also add a shebang to the beginning of your .rb file:

```
#! <shoes directory>/dist/shoes
```

Then executing your script will run it with shoes automatically.